# Can anyone identify this park tree? Is it an elm?

Tags: identification, trees

this is a tree in a park in Hong Kong. All the trees around it have their species labelled, but unfortunately this one does not. Please can anyone identify it?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's a [*Magnolia grandiflora*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnolia_grandiflora) (Southern Magnolia), distinctive from its height, inverted pyramid shape, spotty bark and large leaves. The bark is almost like a beech, smooth. I can see why you might think it was an elm, the vase shape is somewhat similar. This type of tree can grow to 120 feet, superb flowers (if you can see them at that altitude) and useful hard wood.

Comment: Omg, wow, thanks! Are you sure?

Comment: In this world nothing is true except that which is true by definition. The way this site works is that a person who has a different identification is welcome to post it, with the requirement that they specify why they have a different candidate in mind, showing why my contribution is wrong and theirs is superior. Then readers get to vote. Hopefully, the aggregate view leans towards the truth.

Comment: If it's MG hopefully it will bloom soon.

Comment: I agree with the Magnolia ID. I just went out to look at a few of mine, I thought the bark was smoother. But mine look just like that except for many Yellow Belly Sapsucker scars. The fork/crotch is unusual , normally they have a single trunk.